# Peripheral arterial disease and prophylaxis against venous thrombosis

Tags: coronary-bypass

The [general guideline](https://www.surgeons.org/media/19372/VTE_Guidelines.pdf) is that venous thromboembolic disease should be treated with prophylaxis prior to major surgery.

What's the guideline when there is concurrent peripheral arterial disease.  I have heard conflicting opinions from both cardiologists and vascular surgeons.

Comment: Welcome to Health, OldSteve! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. Personalised medical advice is off-topic here. You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: Although the question begins with personal info, the last sentence is the actual question and it's not a request for medical advice. This is a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: It would be perfect without the personal data but I agree it's within our scope.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). It would be great if you could rephrase your question to omit personal data and make it more general. Something along the lines of "if a person has condition A and condition B there are concerns C and D..." and then leave the question on guidelines stand.

Comment: Apologies. I am more used to asking questions on other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The national guideline center says to seek expert opinion before using stockings for venous thromboembolic prophylaxis when peripheral arterial disease is present since there is insufficient data in this situation.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK116514/

If the decision is made not to use stockings or other devices, or medications, then the patient should be closely observed for the development of venous thrombosis.